# How to have a white list of files to be compiled in Gradle NDK build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin

I need to transform an Android app's from Ant to Gradle. This app uses a cross platform C++ library. With Ant we are using make (.mk) files to decide which files are compiled to create the JNI library. I am trying to use the new experimental Gradle version (gradle-experimental:0.7.0-rc1) to do something equivalent to what Ant is doing and white list the files I compile.

The problem is that according to the [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental), this can't be done.

```
    sources.main {
        jni {
            source {
                include "someFile.cpp"  // This is ignored.
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively easy way to do this is to continue using your existing .mk makefiles and call to ndk-build from Gradle like this:

```
// Call external ndk-build(.cmd) script to build the native code
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    def ndkBuildExt = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? ".cmd" : ""
    commandLine "ndk-build${ndkBuildExt}", '-C', file('.').absolutePath,
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

This approach requires the path to your NDK installation to be set in Android Studio's "Project Structure" dialog (File->Project Structure) or by setting the `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` environment variable on the command line.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but I guess that while the plugin is experimental - it is an acceptable solution.